# How to manage failover between two data centers for web app, storage account, and SQL database in azure?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage, azure-web-app-service

I am new to Azure architecture.
I want to manage failover between two data centers.

Example:

**Data center A** has Web apps, storage account, SQL database.

**Data center** B has same services Web apps, storage account, SQL database.

When one of the service goes down from **Data center A**, traffic manager should send request to **Data center B** where all services should up and provide response to requests.

Comment: You should post this to ServerFault. While the general question of "how do I implement DR" is broad/opinion-based and off-topic, there are specific features of Azure you can consider integrating into your app to accomplish your goals (but again, should be discussed on ServerFault, since this isn't a programming question).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure Traffic Manager with in Failover mode: 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/traffic-manager-configure-failover-routing-method/

It'll let you direct all requests to Data Center A by default, but have it fail over to Data Center B if A goes down.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a design [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/sql-database-designing-cloud-solutions-for-disaster-recovery/) you may find useful. It describes how to manage failovers between different regions using SQL database geo-replication and Traffic manager.